# d3-org-chart, how to expand and highlight a node in onNodeClick event

Tags: d3.js, orgchart

```
var chart = new d3.OrgChart()
    .container('.chart-container')
    .data(dataFlattened)
    .nodeWidth((d) => 250)
    .initialZoom(0.7)
    .nodeHeight((d) => 175)
    .childrenMargin((d) => 40)
    .compactMarginBetween((d) => 15)
    .compactMarginPair((d) => 80)
    .nodeContent(function (d, i, arr, state) {
        return `*** html content obmitted ***`;
    })
    .onNodeClick(function (d) {
        // d = id of the node clicked
        // How to expand and change the color of the node here?
    })
    .render();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like the following to highlight a node when you click on it:

```
var chart = new d3.OrgChart()
    .container('.chart-container')
    .data(dataFlattened)
    .nodeWidth((d) => 250)
    .initialZoom(0.7)
    .nodeHeight((d) => 175)
    .childrenMargin((d) => 40)
    .compactMarginBetween((d) => 15)
    .compactMarginPair((d) => 80)
    .onNodeClick(d => chart.setHighlighted(d).render())
    .nodeContent(function (d, i, arr, state) {
        return `*** html content obmitted ***`;
    })
    .onNodeClick(function (d) {
        // d = id of the node clicked
        // How to expand and change the color of the node here?
    })
    .render();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself facing the same situation.
What I was thinking that will be good to reuse `chart.onButtonClick('', node);` function because it actually do the same job. For the highlighting I wrote a function like that:

```
const toggleNodeHighlight = (node?: HierarchyNode) => {
  // clearing prev selected node
  chart.render().clearHighlighting();
  // reusing button click from org chart
  chart.onButtonClick('', node);
  // setting highlight for the actual node and render the chart
  chart.setHighlighted(node.id || '').render();
};
```

And use this function inside like this:

```
.onNodeClick((d: NodeId) => {
      // getting chart state
      const state = chart.getChartState();
      // finding all nodes in chart
      const allNodes = state.allNodes;
      // finding current node, not only id
      const currentNode = allNodes.find((item) => item.id == d);
      // pass it to the function for reusing in onButtonClick
      toggleNodeOpen(currentNode);
    })
```

So bare in mind that you have to reset the styles for the default highlighting: `chart.nodeUpdate((d) => {d3.select('.node-rect').attr('stroke', 'none');})`. And you can check `d.data?._highlighted || d.data?._upToTheRootHighlighted` in your template for rendering chart item and apply appropriate styles.